# Subset one element of a row based on vector of column number

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataset

```
data <- cbind(c(1,2,3),c(1,11,21))
```

I want to extract one element from each row based on the column number given by a vector

```
selectcol <- c(1,2,2)
```

In that particular case the result should be

result

```
1
11
21
```

I have tried

```
resul<-apply(data, 1, [,selectcol])
```

but it does not work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `col` to match the values with `selectcol` and subset `data` with it.

```
data[col(data) == selectcol]
# [1]  1 11 21
```

Answer (score 5):

what if you try

```
 selection <- cbind(1:3, selectcol)
 result <- data[sel]
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me using a function:

```
data <- data.frame(cbind(c(1,2,3),c(1,11,21)))

selectcol <- c(1,2,2)

elems<-vector()
extract_elems <- function(data, selectcol) {
  for ( i in 1:length(selectcol)) {
    elems <- append(elems,data[i,selectcol[i]])
  }
  return(elems)
}

output <- extract_elems(data,selectcol)

> output
[1]  1 11 21
```